# Minha String em C some após For

Tags: c, array, string, for

Minha string `ds` não aparece nos resultados, e isto apenas acontece quando ela antecede o `for`. Tentei usar `while`, `do`, `gets`, `scanf`. A única coisa que funciona é excluir o vetor `nota` dentro do `for`, porém preciso que meu código tenha este vetor. Só quero saber porque meu vetor está colidindo com minha string e como eu posso manter minha variável `ds` intacta...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <locale.h>

// CALCULADORA_DE_MÉDIA

float Calc_Med (float nota[0])
{
float media;

media = (nota[0] + nota[1] + nota[2]) / 3;

return media;
}

main ()
{
setlocale(LC_ALL, "Portuguese");

char al[20], ds[12];

int i, n;

float nota[2], md;

printf("========= CALCULADORA DE MÉDIA =========\n\n");

printf("Digite o nome do Aluno: ");
fgets(al, sizeof(al), stdin);

printf("Digite o nome da Disciplina: ");
fgets(ds, sizeof(ds), stdin);

for ( i = 0 ; i < 3 ; i++ )
{
    n = i + 1;

    printf("Digite o valor da %dº nota: ", n);
    scanf("%f", &nota[i]);
}

md = Calc_Med(nota);

system("cls");

printf("========== RESULTADOS ==========\n\n");
printf("Nome do Aluno: %s\n", &al);
printf("Disciplina Cursada: %s\n", &ds);
printf("Média Alcançada: %.2f\n", md);
printf("\n================================\n\n");

system("pause");

return 0;
}
```

Comment: tome cuidado com vetores. o for esta acessando um valo invalido. diminua o 3 para 2

Answer (score -2, accepted):

quando  você declarou o vetor notas, você declarou ele com tamanho 2. e não 3. isso acontece porque quando declaramos, passamos o tamanho e não a ultima posição.

E quando o sistema roda o programa, digamos que ele reserve um pedacinho da memoria pro programa. Isso faz que as variáveis fiquem tudo aglomerada. É uma explicação bem superficial, mas o que importa, é quem C, é preciso tem muito cuidado com variáveis e principalmente ponteiros. E vetores é um tipo de ponteiro, mas não importa aqui.

Se você corrigir a declaração, bem provável que resolva essa problema.

```
float nota[3], md;
```

Comment: Era isso mesmo, acabei confundindo as coisas. Muitíssimo obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que o erro está no momento da declaração do vetor `float nota[2]`.
Quando declaramos uma variável, o compilador irá reservas pedaços da memória correspondente ao tamanho dela.

O formato para declarar um array em C é o seguinte: `tipo nomeArray [Tamanho];`.
Você declarou um array de tamanho 2, porém dentro do laço `for()` está assumindo que o array tem tamanho 3. Ao fazer isso, na ultima iteração do laço, o valor que você entrará como média irá sobrescrever alguma outra coisa no código, pois estará fora da memória reservada ao array. Teste modificar a função `for()` para `for (i=0; i<2; i++)`, você verá que o código funcionará perfeitamente, apesar de estar tendo como input apenas 2 notas.

Para resolver este problema basta modificar a declaração do seu array para `float nota[3]`, assim o compilador irá disponibilizar memória suficiente para armazenar os 3 valores `float` que desejas utilizar. Acredito que tenha imaginado que ao declarar o array, era necessario informar índice do ultimo elemento, porém deve informar a quantidade de elementos que deseja ter nele.

Comment: Outra forma de fazer o teste que citei no segundo parágrafo é modificar o laço para `for (i=0; i<sizeof(nota)/sizeof(nota[0]); i++)`.

A expressão `sizeof(nota) / sizeof(nota[0])` retorna o número de elementos do array, nesse caso você terá certeza que independente do tamanho do array, o for sempre fará um número de iterações igual ao seu tamanho.